# Updating an entry field, without updating every field

Tags: channel-entries, extension, channel-entries-api

Using the Expression Engine Channel Entries API, is it possible to only update 1 field?

Using the below code, it appears you have to grab all the field data and then re-add it to the fields.

Is it not possible to do the below, just updating a single field (field_id_306).

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->legacy_api->instantiate('channel_entries');

$query = ee()->db->select('title, url_title')
        ->from('exp_channel_titles')
        ->where('entry_id', $entry_id)
        ->get();

if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row();

    $data = array(
        'entry_id' => $entry_id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'url_title' => $row->url_title,
        'field_id_306' => '10'
    );

    ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $channel_id, $entry_id, FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is!

Here's what you need to do ([From the manual](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#id4)) based on your example :

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

//get the row to edit
$query = ee()->db->select('title, url_title')
    ->from('exp_channel_titles')
    ->where('entry_id', $entry_id)
    ->get();

if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row();

    $data = array(
        'entry_id' => $entry_id,
        'title' => $row->title,
        'url_title' => $row->url_title,
        'field_id_306' => '10'
    );

    ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $data);

    $success = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data, $channel_id, $entry_id, FALSE);

    if ( ! $success)
    {
        show_error(implode('<br />', $this->api_channel_entries->errors));
    }
```

Under the hood, you'll notice the main difference in loading the `channel_fields` library and the call to `setup_entry_settings` prior to the `save_entry` call.

It's quite convluted waht happens in `setup_entry_settings` but essentually it loads all the fields for the channel_data table, I beleive it then then sets them to their existing value, or the default value, if they arn't present in the `$data` array, all under the hood.

Ref : https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/api/api_channel_fields.html#Api_channel_fields::setup_entry_settings

Ref : https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/168319/#819749

Disclaimer : I have been using this lately in the context of create_new_entry but the logic is the same I understand.

**Scratch that**
Ok, I've just gone ahead and actually read the function, it doesn't look like it does actually load the existing values however looking at `update_entry` (which is called from `save_entry`, it only builds the query using the columns in your data array, so as long as your entry_id is set correctly (int the `$data` as well as in the `save_entry` parameter) it should update properly.

But please do let me know if it doesn't (with the channel_fields part) please let me kno and I will adjust my understanding accordinly.